# nginx websocket handshake error 400 Useing AWS ELB

Tags: nginx, websocket

I use Rockect-chat.

failed : Error during Websocket handshake : Unexpected response code :400

My setting.
I installed Rocketchat as a sanp on Ubuntu on an AWS EC2 server.
https --> Loadbalancer -------> nginx -----> rocketchat

Nginx setting

```
# Upstreams

upstream backend {

    server 127.0.0.1:3000;

}



server {

    listen 80;

    server_name allthatsneakers.com;

    location / {

     proxy_pass http://backend/;

     proxy_http_version 1.1;
     proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
     proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

     proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header X-Forward-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     proxy_set_header X-Forward-Proto http;
     proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;

     proxy_redirect off;

    }

}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is socket error.

Https -> TCP(HTTPS)

Fixed.